# $\sum=\{0, 1, \#\}$ $C=\{x\#x^R\#x\# | x \in \{0, 1\}^*\}$ Show C̄ is CFL

Tags: context-free-grammar

From my Automata class

$\sum=\{0, 1, \#\}$ $C=\{x\#x^R\#x\# | x \in \{0, 1\}^*\}$ Show C̄ is CFL

I want to use pumping lemma for CFL but I can’t understand which type of language is the complement of C.

Some of my friend proved by:

1. {… demonstration that C is not CFL via PL}
2. Thus C is not a context free language.In other words, it can be said that C̄ is a context free language

But I can’t understand why the fact that **if C is not CFL implies that C̄ is CFL**

I think *that’s not a correct way of thinking*

Comment: Point 2 your friend used is wrong. There are plenty of languages such that neither $C$ nor its complement is context-free. Any non-decidable language is an example.

Comment: I know that, another way to solve the exercise?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear whether you were asking if your friend was correct or for a better solution.
A word is not in $C$ if it doesn't have the form $a\#b\#c\#$, if $a \neq b^R$, or $b \neq c^R$ does this help?